# Is it possible to trigonometrically understand why $\cos(x)$ is even and $\sin(x)$ is odd?

Tags: trigonometry, even-and-odd-functions

Is it possible to trigonometrically understand why $\cos(x)$ is even and $\sin(x)$ is odd?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is: sending $\theta$ to $-\theta$ amounts to flipping the $y$-axis in your drawing, and then the cosine is unaffected since the $x$-axis is fixed, but the sine changes sign (since the $y$-axis is flipped).